# Append-only file write with fsync, on emmc/SSD/sdcard, ext4 or f2fs?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

I am building two operating systems for IoT. The Libertas OS and Hornet OS.

The data APIs are designed to be append-only time series. fsync() is required after each append of byte block to ensure data safety.

The storage could be emmc, SSD, or sdcard. The question is, which filesystem is a better fit for different storage types?

I understand f2fs is designed as append-only. But what about EXT4? Couldn't easily find information about it.

Theoretically, at least for file content, the append shall continue writing on the current underlying block to minimize wearing. Since the file size is changed after append, the file meta-data shall be updated, ideally through append-log.

I also don't know the details of the internal controller of sdcard and emmc, will the controller honor such block level append?

Any insight will be greatly appreciated!